# set the disable property of classes to true in just one line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, syntax

Consider this code fragment:

```
$(".class_cao").attr('disabled',true);
$(".class_ao").attr('disabled',true);
$(".class_es").attr('disabled',true);
$(".class_eps").attr('disabled',true);
$(".class_jo").attr('disabled',true);
```

Is there a way for me to make set the disable property of these classes to true in just one line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the selectors together, separated by commas:

```
$(".class_cao, .class_ao, .class_es, .class_eps, .class_jo").attr('disabled',true);
```

```js
$(".class_cao, .class_ao, .class_es, .class_eps, .class_jo").attr('disabled',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="class_cao">
<input type="checkbox" class="class_ao">
<input type="checkbox" class="class_es">
```

If you frequently find yourself writing something similar to the above, you might consider adding another class to all such elements (or figuring out a different common selector).

Comment: This is exactly the syntax that I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use attribute starts with selector:

```
$("[class^=class_]").attr('disabled',true);
```